# c# Error: “Could Not Find Installable ISAM” in converting Excel file into .CSV file

Tags: c#, excel, exception, csv, isam

I'm working on a project that would be able to **convert Excel files to .CSV File**, I think there are some problems in my C# code that is generating and error message **Could Not Find Installable ISAM**, please help me to sort out my problem.

Code:

```
if (dlgOne.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
{
    StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + srcFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;\"";
}

if (dlgTwo.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
{
    StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + srcFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 1.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
}

OleDbConnection conn = null;

conn = new OleDbConnection(StrConn);
conn.Open();  <------------ throw exception
```

In debug mode the application throws an **exception** (line: `conn.Open();`)
I searched the Internet and I found that I have to put the `Data Source` between one cotes but it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both of the connection strings are wrong.

For .xlsx, it should be:

```
StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + srcFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
```

(Note the extra Xml part, the HDR=YES to indicate your file has headers, the IMEX=1 to treat all data as text and the repositioned semi-colon. You would need different connection strings for .xlsm and .xlsb files - see [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/))

For .xls, it should be:

```
StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + srcFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";
```

(Note the change from Excel 1.0 to Excel 8.0 and the addition of a semi-colon at the end)

Comment: Thank You @barrowc , you are one of those who make the life better

Comment: (Note the change from Excel 1.0 to Excel 8.0 and the addition of a semi-colon at the end), I did not understand what that mean ... but I have noticed that in my generated file there an additional column how can I remove it

Comment: I have noticed that in my generated file there an additional column how can I remove it

Comment: You would need to show the code which actually produces the CSV file to see why the additional column appears. That should probably be a new question

Comment: you already mentioned in your last response that  there will be an additional column (Note the change from Excel 1.0 to Excel 8.0 and the addition of a semi-colon at the end)

Comment: No - that was a description of what had actually changed in the connection string (you had "Excel 1.0" instead of "Excel 8.0" and there was a semi-colon missing) and should have no effect on the structure of the resulting CSV file

Answer (score 1):

Platform plays an important role: if your code compiles in 64-bit and you have Office 32-bit installed (which means all ODBC, ISAM, etc. drivers are 32-bit). Try compiling with "Any CPU" platform